# "client_id not provided" when trying to obtain an access_token

Tags: support, python, oauth2

So I'm trying to [authenticate with the v2 API via oauth2](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). I have a `code`, so I'm `POST`ing to `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token` and ideally get an `access_token` back.

Instead I get an `invalid_request` error saying `client_id not provided` - below is my minimal reproduction case:

```
def oauth_explicit_two(client_id, client_secret, code, redirect_uri):
    params = {'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret,
              'code': code, 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('stackexchange.com', strict=True)
    connection.request('POST', '/oauth/access_token', urllib.urlencode(params))
    #Used the below to route via CharlesProxy and dump request body
    #connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost:8888') # Via CharlesProxy
    #connection.request('POST', 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token', urllib.urlencode(params))
    response = connection.getresponse()
    return response.read()
```

This is being called like so:

```
$ cat example.py
from stackpy import *
print oauth_explicit_two(274, 'elided', 'elided', 'http://stackcompare.com/')
```

And from this:

```
$ python example.py
{"error":{"type":"invalid_request","message":"client_id not provided"}}
```

From [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), I've verified the `POST` body, in which `client_id` most definitely seems to appear:

```
client_secret=elided&code=elided&client_id=274&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackcompare.com%2F
```

So I'm currently at a bit of a loss, as I can't see how I'm not providing the `client_id`...

Comment: (Wasn't really clear whether I should post this on SO or here...)

Comment: here is the correct place

Comment: Hmmm, that's really weird.  That error message is literally behind a "client_id != null" check, I'll dig into the traffic logs and see if anything stands out.  Random thought, can you control the serialization order?  If so, move `client_id` to the very front of the POST body; if the error message changes/goes-away that'd be indicative of an encoding error *somewhere*.

Comment: I'll give it a try, cheers

Comment: Even with `client_id=274` as the sole content of the `POST` body I get the same response. I almost wouldn't believe I was sending it, if I didn't have Charles showing me it in the request body... However I get an (expected) missing-app-secret error if I do this with `curl` - something must not be right my end... (Time for more Charles-debugging!)

Comment: ...well that'd do it - wasn't setting the Content-Type header, apologies!

Comment: @KristianGlass no worries, just post it as an answer so others can get themselves out of similar predicaments.

Answer (score 3):

Well, my bad - I forgot to set the `Content-Type` header. Fixed code snippet:

```
def oauth_explicit_two(client_id, client_secret, code, redirect_uri):
    params = {'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret,
              'code': code, 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} # <---
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('stackexchange.com', strict=True)
    connection.request('POST', '/oauth/access_token', urllib.urlencode(params))
    response = connection.getresponse()
    return response.read()
```